# Is there an industry standard for the following performance metrices for cloud applications?

Tags: load-testing

What all metrics are generally collected as part of Performance Testing of Cloud applications?

To be more specific is there any Industry standard values for the following metrics?.

1. Maximum allowed API response time - How fast my back end API returns results
2. User perception - What is the maximum acceptable time it should take to load a page completely for the user in the browser.

To give more context, my application is a cloud based real time application, where latency hits customer satisfaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best metric to measure User Perceived Performance is Speed Index.
You can read the detailed explanation and how it's calculated:

https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/using-webpagetest/metrics/speed-index

TLDR; "The Speed Index is the average time at which visible parts of the page are displayed.  It is expressed in milliseconds and dependent on size of the view port."

Time to first paint, time to DOM content ready, etc, are all fundamentally flawed in that they measure a single point and do not convey the actual user experience.

Speed Index actually measures the speed that most of the UI is shown to the user which will give you a good measurement for how fast your users perceive your page to load.

You can use webpagetest.org tool to run web performance tests on your app (if it's public facing), choosing a wide range of configuration parameters (i.e. location, network speed and latency, browser, viewport, etc.).

It can even create a video of your web app loading!

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights. Much appreciated.!